# Oracle SQL return value from child table with minimum row number with values in specific list

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a need to select all rows from a table (main table) and join to another table (child table).  In the results set, I want to include one column from the child table, that is only the first row / line number with a column value in a specified list.  If there is no match for the specified list, it should be (null)

Desired Result:

| ORDER_NO | ORDER_DATE | ORDER CUST | ORDER_VALUE | ITEM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 02/14/2022 | 12345 | $1,000.00 | APPLES |
| 2 | 02/13/2022 | 67890 | $5,000.00 | (null) |
| 3 | 02/12/2022 | 45678 | $100.00 | PEARS |

Example:
Main Table: Order Table
Order Number (Handle)
Order Date,
Order Customer,
Order Value

| ORDER_NO | ORDER_DATE | ORDER CUST | ORDER_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 02/14/2022 | 12345 | $1,000.00 |
| 2 | 02/13/2022 | 67890 | $5,000.00 |
| 3 | 02/12/2022 | 45678 | $100.00 |

Child Table: Order Details Tbl
Order Number (Handle)
Line Number = Order Line No
Ordered Item,
Ordered Qty

| ORDER_NO | LINE_NO | ITEM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | **APPLES** |
| 1 | 20 | ORANGES |
| 1 | 30 | LETTUCE |
| 2 | 10 | BROCCOLI |
| 2 | 20 | CAULIFLOWER |
| 2 | 30 | LETTUCE |
| 3 | 10 | KALE |
| 3 | 20 | RADISHES |
| 3 | 30 | **PEARS** |

In this example, the returned column is essentially the first line of the order that is a fruit, not a vegetable.  And if the order includes no matching fruit, null is returned.

What my code is thus far:

```
SELECT
   MAIN.ORDER_NO,
   MAIN.ORDER_DATE,
   MAIN.ORDER_CUST,
   MAIN.ORDER_VALUE,
   B.ITEM
FROM
   MAIN
   LEFT JOIN
   (
   SELECT
      CHILD.ORDER_NO,
      CHILD.LINE_NO,
      CHILD.ITEM
   FROM
      CHILD
   WHERE
      CHILD.ORDER_NO||'_'||LINE_NO IN
        (
        SELECT
          CHILD.ORDER_NO||'_'||MIN(LINE_NO) AS ORDER_LINE_NO
        FROM
          CHILD
        WHERE
          CHILD.ITEM IN ('APPLES','ORANGES','PEACHES','PEARS','GRAPES')
        GROUP BY
          CHILD.ORDER_NO
        )
    ) B ON MAIN.ORDER_NO = B.ORDER_NO
'''

This code is of course not working as desired, as table 'B' is including all results from CHILD.
```

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 12, you can use:

```sql
SELECT o.*,
       d.item
FROM   orders o
       LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL(
         SELECT *
         FROM   order_details d
         WHERE  o.order_no = d.order_no
         AND    item IN ('APPLES','ORANGES','PEACHES','PEARS','GRAPES')
         ORDER BY line_no ASC
         FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
       ) d
       ON (1 = 1)
```

In earlier versions you can use:

```sql
SELECT o.*,
       d.item
FROM   orders o
       LEFT OUTER JOIN(
         SELECT d.*,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY order_no ORDER BY line_no ASC)
                  AS rn
         FROM   order_details d
         WHERE  item IN ('APPLES','ORANGES','PEACHES','PEARS','GRAPES')
       ) d
       ON (o.order_no = d.order_no AND rn = 1)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE orders (ORDER_NO, ORDER_DATE, ORDER_CUST, ORDER_VALUE) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2022-02-14', 12345, 1000.00 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2022-02-13', 67890, 5000.00 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2022-02-12', 45678,  100.00 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Order_Details (ORDER_NO, LINE_NO, ITEM) AS
SELECT 1, 10, 'APPLES'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 20, 'ORANGES'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 30, 'LETTUCE'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 10, 'BROCCOLI'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 20, 'CAULIFLOWER' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 30, 'LETTUCE'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 10, 'KALE'        FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 20, 'RADISHES'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 30, 'PEARS'       FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | ORDER_NO | ORDER_DATE | ORDER_CUST | ORDER_VALUE | ITEM |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 2022-02-14 00:00:00 | 12345 | 1000 | APPLES |
> | 2 | 2022-02-13 00:00:00 | 67890 | 5000 | *null* |
> | 3 | 2022-02-12 00:00:00 | 45678 | 100 | PEARS |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1febaf59420a459f136013aae7734eb0)*